# Error when cloning a project from GitLab, but not when cloning a project from GitHub

Tags: git, github, gitlab, tortoisegit

I am maintaining several different projects on both GitHub (public) and GitLab (private).

For some reason, I recently started getting an error when cloning my projects on GitLab:

```
The project you were looking for could not be found
```

I get the same error when trying to push or pull.

It used to work for one of my GitLab projects up until recently, when I encountered an error my other GitLab project, tried to resolve it, and ended up getting this error both of them.

I don't get this error on any of my GitHub projects.

Here are the URLs that I am using:

- GitHub: https://github.com/path_to/my_project1.git
- GitLab: https://gitlab.com/path_to/my_project2.git

For a Git client, I am using TortoiseGit-2.5.0.0-64bit.

Side note:

Perhaps my problem is that there are several entities here which I am really unable to understand the hierarchy between them:

- TortoiseGIT (locally)
- Git for Windows (locally)
- GitHub / GitLab (remotely)

I guess I should configure my credentials (username, password and perhaps SSH public/private keys) somewhere, but I'm not really sure where.

I tried both on TortoiseGIT, and in my account on GitLab.